# python unittest discover doesn't work in ubuntu

Tags: python-unittest

So I have followed everything that I need to make automatic unit test discovery work

my project structure is like this

```
projectroot
          |---src
          |     |--app.py
          |     |--__init__.py
          |----__init__.py
          |---test
          |     |--test_app.py
          |     |--__init__.py
```

I run the following command from projectroot

```
projectroot>> python -m unittest discover -s test
```

works fine in windows. It is able to discover all the tests under test folder and runs them successfully.

however, when I try the same on an ubuntu machine, it says Ran(0) tests and never discovers any unit tests under test folder.

Does anyone know if there is anything operating system specific going on here ?

Comment: Not sure but you have two init files in your projectroot, I don't think you need an init file in your project root.

Comment: i had that here by mistake. It's not there in reality. i'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked like it was about using -p switch to scan the right pattern of files and discover.

The following worked. Used -p (pattern) attribute to discover/run the unit tests in ubuntu

python -m unittest discover -s test -p "T*.py"

Note: 1. all my test cases start with "T" e.g. Test_check.py 2. "test" is the package where all my test cases are.